# Dell 62xx (6224) QinQ configuration (Double-Vlan)

Tags: networking, dell

I have a few Dell 6224 and a bunch of 3524's and some 5324 - with the latest firmware.

I need to configure QinQ between ports, conveniently called "Customer port" on the 35xx and the 53xx, and it works like a charm there, can even do the config right from GUI - set the port to customer mode, and tag the VLAN to use for the transport. (ingress data tag data is ignored and a outer heading added for transport, egress strips the outer tag).

But, the 62xx will not play nicely - it has what is called "double-VLAN" or dvlan-tunnel, which is supposed to provide the same features.
The manual is junk and support haven't provided an answer in days now.
The best online info I could find was at [community.dell.com](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/network-switches/f/866/p/19265885/19563705.aspx),
but that still doesn't tell me the correct way of using dvlan-tunnel - as soon as I enable it on any interface, all other trunks stops forwarding.

Does anyone know how to configure this correctly without bringing down the rest of the switch, when you have a mix of normal q-tags and need some q-in-q for just a port or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'mode dvlan-tunnel' option on the 62xx switches does work, but it's "backwards". You enable the 'mode dvlan-tunnel' option not (as one would expect) on push/pop ports, but instead on *all* trunks that will carry your provider tags. Then you set your customer-facing push/pop ports as standard access ports with the access vlan of your provider (outer) tag, and let customers do their thing within.

Comment: wow - so there is no way to configure without downtime unless I had set it on all regular trunks from the beginning.. heh..  what a wonderful world - Dell really should stick to one OS when it comes to its switches... thank you

Comment: btw that did work just fine - and looking at the original URL it was right in there, the answer was too complicated on that page for my farted out brain to get :)  I don't know why that wouldn't be a default option on all trunk ports then, and to explicitly turn it off for "customer ports"... oh well, Dell works in mysterious ways